# SKLEARN: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

working with sklearn and getting an error on categorical_features. I understand that it's deprecated, but I really don't know who to rework this to use ColumnTransformer. Any help much appreciated.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
y = houses_df['house_type'].values
y_labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
y = y_labelencoder.fit_transform(y)

y=y.reshape(-1,1)
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
Y = onehotencoder.fit(y)
Y.shape
```

Comment: It dont take any parameter

Comment: which column you are trying to encode?

Comment: The house_type column. Thanks for having a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) do not take any parameter called `categorical_features`. If you do not specify any parameter, it will take categories as `auto`.
If you want specific categories to be one hot encoded, use **`categories`** parameter.

Use this.

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
new_y = onehotencoder.fit_transform(y)
print(new_y.shape)
print(new_y.toarray())
```

Comment: That gives me this error: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-2041f0da80c8> in <module>()
      2 onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
      3 Y = onehotencoder.fit(y)
----> 4 Y.shape

AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'shape'